# Textures as background for Sprites in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, sprite, textures

In the same way that I can fill an Sprite with an specific color, is there any way to use my own texture image as background for Sprites in Flex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Graphics.beginBitmapFill() method and then draw shapes with standard methods. There are other methods though. For example, I use BitmapFill instance in Flex to create a "checkered background":

```
private static function getCheckeredBitmapData() : BitmapData {
    if (_checkeredBitmapData == null) {
        _checkeredBitmapData = new BitmapData(16, 16, false, 0xCCCCCC);
        _checkeredBitmapData.fillRect(new Rectangle(0, 0, 8, 8), 0xFFFFFF);
        _checkeredBitmapData.fillRect(new Rectangle(8, 8, 16, 16), 0xFFFFFF);
    }
    return _checkeredBitmapData;
}
```

...

```
<s:fill>
    <s:BitmapFill source="{getCheckeredBitmapData()}" fillMode="repeat"/>
</s:fill>
```

Comment: Is it work with an specific texture? I don't want to create in runtime. I have my own texture image (i.e., png) and I want to use it as a texture background.